# In React how do I use a conditional with rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple notification window, and as notifications are accepted/declined I remove the object from the `notifications` array.

This is my bit of code for handling displaying messages:

```
render: function() {
  return (
      <div className="chatwindowheight">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="large-12 columns">
            <div className="large-8 columns">
              <p className="thin partyHeader">Party <i className="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i></p>
            </div>

            <div className="large-4 columns">
              <i className="fa fa-users pull-right"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row chatwindowheight">
          <div className="large-12 small-12 columns chatwindow" id="scrolldown">
          <br/>
            {
              this.state.messages.map((message, i) => {
                return (
                    <MessageComponent key={i}
                                      username={message.username}
                                      message={message.message}
                                      whos={message.classed} />
                  );
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      <ChatSendComponent onChatSubmit={this.handleChatSubmit}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I want is to have something like

```
if (this.state.messages.length === 0) {
  return (
    <p>You have no new notifications.</p>
  )    
}
```

but when I try to wrap something like that around the current loop, it tells me that `if` is an error. New to React so just trying to understand the best method for approaching this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some various resolve your problem: 
1.

```
{ this.state.messages.length > 0 ?
  this.state.messages.map((message, i) => {
    return (
     <MessageComponent key={i}
       username={message.username}
       message={message.message}
       whos={message.classed} />
     );
 }) : 'You have messages'
}
```

2. Remove you map up to render function and prepare your data there: 

   `function render() {
     var message='';
     if (this.state.messages.length) {
     }
   }
   <b>{message}</b>`

Comment: Your first answer seems to work great, the only problem is, is it doesn't seem to be reactive, is there a way to make it switch back to the loop when a new notification gets put into the array? Hope I made sense.

Comment: When state is chages the component is renders. It's reactive. We use this way to define condition inside jsx. There is the other way to do it: http://tinyurl.com/ecma-do

Comment: This was my mistake, it worked in the first example I simply had changed something earlier in the day and didn't realize it till now because I hadn't restarted the server so the server side changes hadn't taken effect. Thanks it works fantastic.